# How can I override a native JS function ( canvas's drawImage() ) in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, overriding

I need to execute some code at every call of the function drawImage() done on a canvas 2D context.

```
game.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
game.ctx = game.canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Unfortunately, it isn't as easy as it looks.

I tried to do this:

```
game.ctx.drawImageOld = game.ctx.drawImage;
game.ctx.drawImage = function(i,x,y,u,v){console.log("ok"); game.ctx.drawImageOld(i,x,y,u,v);}
game.ctx.drawImage(myImage, 10, 10);
// logs "ok" two times on FF
```

and this

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImageOld = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImage;
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImage = function(i,x,y,u,v){console.log("ok"); this.drawImageOld(i,x,y,u,v);}
game.ctx.drawImage(myImage, 10, 10);
// logs "ok" two times
```

But the native drawImage is never executed...

How can I do it? ot is there another way to "detect" a function call?

Thanks.

Comment: Call `this.drawImageOld` instead of `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImageOld`

Comment: thanks, but it also logs "ok" two times then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImageOld(i,x,y,u,v);
```

then inside `drawImageOld`, `this` will refer to `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype`, not to the actual Context2D instance. That's basically what the error is telling you.

You can use [`.call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to explicitly pass the instance along:

```
(function() {
    var orig_drawImage = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImage;

    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImage = function() {
        console.log("ok");
        orig_drawImage.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}());
```

Then being said, it is not guaranteed that this will work in all browsers. Host objects, i.e. object not covered by the ECMAScript specification, don't always have to follow all the rules. Some browsers might also define  `drawImage` as readonly.